# Angular 5: How to load multiple custom child components for a screen?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

**Background**

I'm writing an enterprise application in Angular 5. One of the large screens I'm working on has many tabs and child components. A majority of clients will get the same version of the screen, but a client or two want custom changes under a couple of tabs.

**Question**

How do I dynamically load custom components for those couple of tabs where the client wants changes? I know I could use async lazy module loading to load a whole new screen specific for that client, but it seems it would be more efficient to only swap out the child components that have changes rather than the whole screen.

Async loading appears to be the way to go as you can use canLoad to not load unnecessary code for each client. At the child level, if you have multiple components at the same child level to swap, you could try to use named router outlets with async modules for the child components. However, I ran into a [bug with async loading and the named router outlets](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-301787482).

Anyone have any other ideas?

**Code**

Here is the code for the routes I tried when exploring the above idea. The core screen is the parent level screen, async loaded.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: CoreScreenComponent,
    children: [
        { 
            path: 'x-core',
            loadChildren: "app/components/core-component-x/core-component-x.module#CoreComponentXComponent",
            outlet: 'x' 
        },
        { 
            path: 'x-client',
            loadChildren: "app/components/client-component-x/client-component-x.module#ClientComponentXComponent",
            outlet: 'x' 
        },
        { 
            path: 'y-core', 
            loadChildren: "app/components/core-component-y/core-component-y.module#CoreComponentYComponent",
            outlet: 'y'
        },
        { 
            path: 'y-client',
            loadChildren: "app/components/client-component-y/client-component-y.module#ClientComponentyComponent",
            outlet: 'y' 
        },
    ]
}];
```